Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' error
I am trying to run a react native app, build using react-native cli but it is giving me this error:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

WindowsRegistry is not supported on this operating system.

I have tried a cleaning up project using ./gradlew clean but still it gives the some error
